# Set OSX application frame between dock and menu

Tags: objective-c, macos, size, frame, nswindow

I'm new in Objective-c, I don't know how to set the frame height between menu bar and Dock. I look up many questions about it, and here is my code :

I create a `NSWindowController` file called `MainWindowController`.

**MainWindowController.m**

```
#import "MainWindowController.h"

@interface MainWindowController ()

@end

@implementation MainWindowController

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];

    int screenWidth = [NSScreen mainScreen].frame.size.width;
    int screenHeight = [NSScreen mainScreen].frame.size.height;

    [self.window setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight) display:YES];
    [self.window setContentSize:NSMakeSize(screenWidth, screenHeight)];
    [self.window setContentMaxSize:NSMakeSize(screenWidth, screenHeight - self.window.dockTile.size.height)];
    [self.window setContentMinSize:NSMakeSize(screenWidth, screenHeight - self.window.dockTile.size.height)];
    [self.window setMaxFullScreenContentSize:NSMakeSize(screenWidth, screenHeight - self.window.dockTile.size.height)];
    [self.window setMinFullScreenContentSize:NSMakeSize(screenWidth, screenHeight - self.window.dockTile.size.height)];
    [self.window toggleFullScreen:self];

    // Set Title Bar

    self.window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = YES;
    self.window.styleMask |= NSWindowStyleMaskFullSizeContentView;
}

@end
```

but it went out like: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Uyf.png)

How can I set the frame beyond dock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the screen size use [`-[NSScreen frame]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000333-CJBBEFJG) on an instance received through e.g. [`+[NSScreen mainScreen]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000333-mainScreen) or [`-[NSWindow screen]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-screen).
To get the visible part without the dock and menu bar, use [`-[NSScreen visibleFrame]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScreen_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000333-visibleFrame).

Keep in mind that the full desktop can stretch over multiple screens.